# What are my options for joining together multiple audio tracks into a single file (OS X and ?)?

Tags: macos

I sometimes get CDs of teachings or seminars where someone has split the audio into a bunch of 5 minute segments and I'd prefer that they were in a single long file and that iTunes just remembered where I was in them for me.

However, I'm not sure the best way to accomplish this.

1. I could use brute force and jump into Audacity and simply cut and paste all the audio files together.  This seems stupid but I know it would work.
2. I could use programs like [Join Together](http://www.dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/jointogether.php) or [Audio Book Builder](http://www.splasm.com/audiobookbuilder/) but both of them seem more complicated than what I want to do.  Join Together requires that I import the songs first and Audio Book Builder is for, well, building audio books, which is not really what I want to do.  Join Together at least is free but Audio Book Builder is $10 (not that much, but whatever).
3. ?

I'm assuming there's got to be some what to do something along the lines of `cat 1.mp3 2.mp3 3.mp3 > long.mp3` but I know there is some metadata in mp3s at least.  However, audio on CDs is almost always .aiff and I have no idea if that contains metadata or if it's literally just a stream of bits.

I'd prefer a Mac solution but I figured it'd be good to collect other OS solutions as well.

Answer (score 3):

How about just changing the options on the tracks?  Select a track in iTunes, then type command-i (or select "Get Info" from the "File" menu).  In the dialog that appears, click the "Options" tab.  Then check the checkboxes for "Part of a gapless album" and "Remember playback position."  Now you should be able to seamlessly listen to sequential tracks and iTunes should remember your playback position.

[image: iTunes options]